# How to modify configuration file for another C# assembly?

Tags: app-config, configuration-files, .net-assembly, settings

I have a .NET assembly *A* with `app.config` settings file generated by framework. Actually, it is called `A.dll.config`. I want to access and modify this settings file from another .NET assembly *B*. The problem is, the `A.dll.config` file for *A* is located somewhere in the current user profile directory, as it should be, and I don't know where to find it. I know only where the assembly *A* is located.

So, how can I locate the `app.config` file given the path to the assembly?

The other question is, what if the assembly *A* was not loaded at the first time I'm trying to access its configuration file from the *B*? I assume, the configuration file is not generated at this time. Is it possible to manually load the *A* to force it to generate appropriate configuration file?

Comment: This isn't going to work, an app.dll.config will never be loaded.  Only the app.exe.config file is considered.  You can merge the app settings by hand but this is no joy.  Realistically, you cannot use app settings in a class library, they are only good enough for simple EXE apps.

Comment: However, I can make modifications to properties in `Properties.Settings.Default`, and they persist after calling the `Save()` method. The strange thing is, I cannot locate neither `A.dll.config`, nor `MyApp.dll.config` files in windows user directories, while `A.dll.config` in my solution directory doesn't change.